# Make Rufus show internal hard drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, rufus

I wanted to install Windows on my other hard drive with **Rufus** by using Windows10 ISO and without using any external USB/CD/DVD.

So I plugged in the other drive to my motherboard and I can see the drive on my PC, as well as DiskManager.

However, Rufus doesn't show it..?

How to make Rufus show internal hard drives?

Comment: Try `ALT+F` in Rufus to enable fixed internal storage (hard drives).

Comment: You want to install windows installation media to an internal hard drive?  So you can install from it I presume?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Rufus dev here. If you **REALLY** want to try to play with internal drives, there is a non-publicized cheat mode (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F` -- be mindful that this is **not** the same as `Alt`-`F`) that **may** list internal drives, such as SATA and so on, provided they have been set as REMOVABLE by your BIOS or UEFI firmware. For instance, this cheat mode should let Rufus list properly configured eSATA drives, that you may have plugged into your motherboard.

Of course, if you use this **UNSUPPORTED** cheat mode, you are 100% on your own.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What's the difference between CTRL ALT F and ALT F?

Comment: `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F` __may__ be able to list internal SATA drives, __IF__ they are seen by Windows as eSATA/removable drives. On the other hand, `Alt`-`F` will only list USB devices.

Comment: Wish it listed internal fixed drives... :)

Comment: `Ctrl Alt F` solved my problem with an NVMe WDCS500G2B0C drive in an external Thunderbolt 4 enclosure not showing up. For reference, this same NVMe drive showed up normally when connected via a 10gbps USB3 enclosure.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Rufus developers don't have a plan to support Internal Hard Drives. [do you plan to support internal HDDs SSDs?](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#do-you-plan-to-support-internal-hddsssds).

To install windows from internal HD you can use:

[Yumi Multiboot UEFI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) if you have (Secret boot / GPT disk / UEFI).

or [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) if you have an MBR hard disk.

Comment: Yes, YUMI works.

Comment: What about UTmake?